# NSToolbar icons greyed out

Tags: swift, macos, window, toolbar, nswindowcontroller

I'm trying to setup an `NSToolbar` with custom `NSToolbarItem`'s. Therefore I removed all default items from the library's toolbar and added two `NSToolbarItem`'s. I've created a custom class `PreferencesViewController` for the window controller, entered it's name in the storyboard as the class name and connected the toolbar items with `IBActions` in the custom class.

But when I run the app, the items are greyed out and I can't click on them.
[image]

This is the code for my `PreferencesWindowController`

```
class PreferencesWindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: NSToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var syncToolbarItem: NSToolbarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var advancedToolbarItem: NSToolbarItem!


    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Setup window
        self.window?.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
        self.window?.styleMask.remove(.miniaturizable)
        self.window?.center()

        toolbar.allowsExtensionItems = false
        toolbar.allowsUserCustomization = false
        toolbar.displayMode = .iconAndLabel
        toolbar.selectedItemIdentifier = syncToolbarItem.itemIdentifier
    }


    @IBAction func showSyncViewController(_ sender: Any) {
        print("show sync")
    }


    @IBAction func showAdvancedViewController(_ sender: Any) {
        print("show advanced")
    }
}
```

A little bit more context:
I am loading and showing the window programmatically. So I've created a separate storyboard named `Preferences.storyboard`, with a window controller plus toolbar and a view controller.
The window is presented through the following code:

```
// Load window
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Preferences", bundle: nil)
guard let windowCtrl = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: .init(stringLiteral: "preferencesID")) as? PreferencesWindowController else { return }

// Present window
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
windowCtrl.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
windowCtrl.window?.delegate = self
```

Comment: Are the `IBAction`s connected? Menu and tool bar items without actions are disabled by default.

Comment: Yes, I've double checked it in the Interface Builder by right clicking on the items.

Comment: Check again. Replace `Any` with `NSToolbarItem` in both actions to avoid connecting the wrong UI element.

Comment: Ok, I did that. Since there were no error I assume the correct UI elements were connected. I've also hovered over the `IBAction`s in the assistant editor and it highlighted to correct `NSToolbarItem`s in the storyboard.

Comment: Do you keep a strong reference to `windowCtrl`?

Comment: No I didn't. I've now added a property in my `PreferencesWindowController` to store the `windowCtrl` and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot! Do you have an explanation, what exactly the problem is, when not keeping a strong reference to the window controller?

Comment: ARC releases the window controller when there's no strong reference. A toolbar item with `autovalidates` on is disabled when no object will handle the action.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, that was it. Keeping a strong reference to the window solved the problem! I would accept that as an answer if you post it.

Comment: +1 to Willeke's suggestion.  I had some legacy code I was retrofitting, and keeping a strong reference to the window controller was the fix there as well.

Comment: @Willeke your suggestion was the solution. I'd never expected that the WindowController could be release